# Is “How tiresome are you” ungrammatical?

Tags: questions, subject-verb-inversion

On a post on twitter a girl had sent messages to her boyfriend and one of the messages was

> How tiresome are you.

People were saying that it is grammatically incorrect but I don't understand why since it makes sense in my native language.

<sub>My grammar sucks because I learned english from the internet</sub>

Comment: I hope [this wasn't the  X (formerly Twitter) post](https://twitter.com/minaaofcc/status/1753672846658699384) because Lord help us that **how tiresome r u** was viewed by 1.4 million people and liked by 26.1K.

Comment: Maybe she meant to ask if he was **tired** and instead remarked on how **tiresome** (boring, annoying) he was (an insult, not a question).

Comment: Or it was meant to be "How tiresome you are." That is an exclamatory sentence rather than a question. This is supported by the absence of a question mark.

Comment: Don't tell me you haven't noticed that on twitter or in SMSs punctuation is free of rules! You ca use ,, or ,,, or . or ! or whatever. I am not saying it is meaningless; there are tendencies to attach meaning to certain patterns, to certain structures. From such messages you should not expect grammar, just meaning. They might however have confused "tiresome" with "quick to get tired".

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatical and makes sense, but only in the (very unlikely) interpretation of it as a question about the degree of your tiresomeness.

> How tiresome are you?

i.e. Tell me how tiresome you are.

But it was almost certainly meant as an exclamation, not a question, and so does not take subject inversion:

> How tiresome you are!

i.e. I think you are very tiresome.

Comment: I think it's fine as an inversion, perhaps for emphasis or variety. It expresses exasperation,  consternation, resignation—your choice. Think of Hamlet saying, "Oh, what a rogue and peasant slave am I!"

Comment: This type of inversion is quirky nowadays. Not ungrammatical, but its acceptability is moot.

Comment: Is this really a a question that can be addressed grammatically?  I tend to fo with Greenbaum in his Oxford English Grammar, in which he prefers to use the term 'non-standard' rather than 'ungrammatical'.  The danger is that a 'non-standard' locution on a social media post could acquire the status of 'standard' very quickly without half or more of the speakers being aware.  Is there is case, I wonder, for dictionaries to exercise great caution about the use of social media as a statistical basis for deciding the status of such a locution?

Comment: It being a question is quite plausible. Something like "How stupid are you?" (or "Just how stupid are you?", "Are you really that stupid?", etc) would be commonly addressed to someone being very stupid. And it works with other qualities. But lack of question mark leaves it up in the air.

Comment: @StuartF "How stupid are you?" has practically become an idiom. I'm not sure you can stick any pejorative adjective in there with the same sarcastic effect. The question in the OP just sounds weird.

Comment: @Barmar "How tiresome are you?" sounds perfectly natural to me—it's obviously intended as a rhetorical question. One might also sarcastically say "How clever are you?", or say the same the same thing sincerely to a pet or small child.

Comment: @Notso Except for "stupid" I don't think I've ever heard anything like that. As the answer says, it's more common to say "How tiresome you are" with an exasperated tone. Of course, you can make a rhetorical statement about anything, but this seems like a weird thing to say to me.

Comment: @Barmar personally I can't say I've ever heard anyone say "How tiresome you are" in natural conversation over 30 years variously in England, South Africa, and Australia—I've only read it in books. Perhaps "How tiresome can you be?" sounds more natural to you? Either way I think by far the most common way to express the sentiment would be "You're so tiresome!"

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of subject-auxiliary inversion in an exclamative clause, where we would normally expect "How tiresome you are!" As [Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) note, this is "relatively infrequent"; in fact, it's characteristic of "fairly literary style" (p. 920). They give the example:

> How rarely does one see such chivalry nowadays!

As they note, this makes the structure of the exclamation more like that of an interrogative clause, so that grammatically the sentence can be interpreted either as an exclamative clause or as an interrogative one, depending on prosody and punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

If it was intended as a rhetorical question (which I'd argue it probably was, given the context of text messages between romantic partners), then it's only grammatically incorrect because it lacks a question mark (and even that depends on [who](https://web.archive.org/web/20060908101340/http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/question.htm) you [ask](https://www.whitesmoke.com/question-mark-usage)). Even if we agree that in formal writing a rhetorical question must be accompanied by a question mark, people will usually bend (or ignore) the rules when texting close acquaintances or posting online.